# 2 simple loops not working together, segmentation fault

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

ok, so either i use FOR or WHILE loop, they can work alone, but when i type the same type of loop after it, it compiles but after running it gives me the error "segmentation fault (core dumped)" OR sometimes "Bus error core dumped"

I am using 2  2D-arrays right now, i need to make generic matrix program. Right now the code is for input. If i add one of the loop between /* and */, the remaining loop works fine!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, k, l; //I, J for array matrix a, K, L for matrix b
int a[i][j]; //matrix of size i by j
int b[k][l];
int rowa=0, cola=0, rowb=0, colb=0;
//rowa is ROW no. of array a and colb e.g Column no. for array b

printf("size of matrix a: ");
scanf("%d\n%d", &i, &j); //i is row, j is column

printf("size of matrix b: ");
scanf("%d\n%d", &k, &l); //k is row, l is column


while (rowa < i)
{
    while (cola < j)
    {
    statements
    }
statements
}

while (rowb < k)
{
        while (colb < l)
    {
    statements
    }
statements
}

return 0;
}
```

So what do i do? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If your on a linux based system, I'd recommend `gdb`. And, please fix your indentation :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using uninitialized variables which results in ***undefined behavior*** :

```
int i, j, k, l; //I, J for array matrix a, K, L for matrix b
int a[i][j]; //matrix of size i by j
...
printf("size of matrix a: ");
scanf("%d\n%d", &i, &j); //i is row, j is column
```

You should initialize `i` and `j` prior to `a[i][j]` declaration, i.e

```
printf("size of matrix a: ");
scanf("%d\n%d", &i, &j);
// initialize the matrix:
int a[i][j];
```

Comment: Yup, thanks. Now placed printfscanf before initialization of arrays, works fine. seems logical now.